# Size of the set of palindromic functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Solve and prove for the size of the the set of functions from k bits to 2x bits where the output bitstrings are palindromic (the first x bits are the reverse bitstring of the last x bits).

Because they're bitstrings, I would assume it's something along the lines of $2^{{x2}^{(k/2)+1}}$, but I'm not sure. Any guidance?

Comment: The domain of our functions  is the set of $k$-bit words, of which there are $2^k$. It looks as if we want to count the functions from this set to the set of $2^x$ $x$-bit words, for once the first $x$ bits are given, the rest are determined. Then the number of functions has size $(2^x)^{2^k}$, or equivalently $2^{x2^k}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $n^m$ functions from a set of $m$ elements to a set of $n$ elements. Here $m=2^k$ ($k$-bit words) and $n=2^x$, because the first $x$ bits determine the palindrome. Hence, $n^m=2^{x2^k}$. (Exactly what  André Nicolas said in a comment.)